# When cutting a polygon with a polyline the geometry engine will group certain peices together?? Arcgis javascript api

Tags: javascript, geometry, cut, arcgis-js-api

When preforming a cut action on a polygon with a polyline, some of the returned geometries are grouped while others are not?

I have a simple program where the user can create a polygon with a SketchViewModel. Then the user creates a polyline with a SketchViewModel. I then take the geometry from each sketch and preform a cut from the geometryEngine. I get an array of geometries from the cut and add them to the layer while removing the original polygon and polyline. I would expect to get each subdivided piece individually but for some reason some get grouped together as one geometry even if they're not connected.

```
   //polylineLayer and polygonLayer are graphiclayers
   //submit is a html button to call the execution
   submit.addEventListener("click", function() {

   //subDivisions is an Geometry[] for the produced geometries
   //ex. one line through a circle polygon would produce
   // two geometries of each half. (this works)
   // anything more complicated starts having grouping issues
   // (see pictures)
   var subDivisions = 
         geometryEngine.cut(polygonLayer.graphics.getItemAt(0).geometry, 
         polylineLayer.graphics.getItemAt(0).geometry);
    polygonLayer.removeAll();
    polylineLayer.removeAll();
    //show the number of subdivisions
    alert("size: " + subDivisions.length);
    // add created geometries to the graphiclayer
    for (var i = 0; i < subDivisions.length; i++){
           tempGraphic = new Graphic ({
           geometry: subDivisions[i]                    
           });
           polygonLayer.graphics.add(tempGraphic,i);

        }
    });
```

(sorry for the links to photos I don't have 10 reputation to post photos and this is a very visual project/issue)

Open screen:
https://ibb.co/WDcgmSn

Draw first polygon:
https://ibb.co/wd6CDbV

Draw polyline to cut polygon:
https://ibb.co/BG32863

Expected subdivisions - 10 Actual - 7:
https://ibb.co/0VMsHGg

Some are split into individual polygons:
https://ibb.co/SKXCJR8

Others are not:
https://ibb.co/7WqNB9q

All broken up pieces:
https://ibb.co/Pr0smrw

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could comment instead of just answer but hard to say with out code.

Basically you are getting multipart polygons, you need to break those up.

Use a split in your array to break up the multi-part polygons split("]],[[")

Simplify Polygons using a geometry service would be worth a shot too. (before and after cutting)

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/geometry-service.htm

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into the "explode" feature in other eris products but it looks like there's no such thing in the JS api. I'll try the simplify polygons. Right now I'm working on splitting up the polygons by "rings" but I'm having issues with the spacial references.